# Why is solution to this inequality equal to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given inequality
$$-5(1- x)^2 < 3x + 11$$
which after algebraic manipulation looks like
$$5x^2 - 7x + 16 > 0,$$
it is obvious that it's discriminant is equal to $\Delta = -271$. In my book it is shown, that solution is equal to $\mathbb{R}$. How so?

Comment: Since the discriminant is negative, there are no real roots. Since there are no real roots, the entire parabola is either above or below the $x$-axis. It's easy to confirm that the parabola is above, so for any value of $x$, the output is positive, so the inequality is true for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: And what about inequality $2x^2 - 5x +5 \leq 0$, for example? It's discriminant is -15, but it has no solution (according to the book). I'm really confused now. :)

Comment: Same idea: for any value of $x$, that parabolic expression is *positive* (so, explicitly **not** less than or equal to zero), so that inequality is never true.

Comment: Oh, I forget about the fact that it is $\leq 0$... My fault, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of $2x^2-7x+16$ is obviously positive when $x=0$.

The only way for the value to be negative for some $x$ would be if it passes through $0$ between $x=0$ and that point.

But since the discriminant is negative, the function never crosses the $x$-axis -- so the function values must stay above it.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the square is the clearest way to show this.
This inequality is equivalent to
$$(x-7/10)^2>-271/100$$
which is clearly always true, as a squared number is always greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$5x^2 - 7x + 16=5(x^2-7/2x+16/5)$$

$$=5(x^2-2•7/4x+16/5)=5(x^2-2•7/4x+(7/4)^2-(7/4)^2+16/5)$$

$$=5[(x-7/4)^2-(7/4)^2+16/5)$$
$$=5(x-7/4)^2+16-5•49/16$$
$$=5(x-7/4)^2+11/16$$

Hence, you add a positive number to a square wich is also always positive or Zero. This implies the expression is positive for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.